# Function 1/x is not locally integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have to show, that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

How to show it formally?

Comment: There is one specific point you need to look at...

Comment: I know, it's zero, where both $1/x ^ {+}$ and $1/x ^ {-}$  grow to infinity...

Comment: Any clue? I'm pretty bad at measure theory...

Comment: So, show that $\int_I 1/|x|$ is infinite for some closed interval $I$ containing $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that a function $f$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb R$ if for each compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb R$, $f\chi_K$ is integrable.

Here, taking $K=[0,1]$ we can see that $f$ is not integrable on $K$ (the value at $0$ does not matter as we work almost everywhere). Indeed, we can either compute $\int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac 1x\mathrm dx$ or pick a sequence of simple functions smaller than $f$ and such that $\int_K f_n(x)\mathrm dx\geqslant n$.

Comment: $\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = \log(1)-log(\epsilon)$ and when $\epsilon$ tends to $0$, $log(\epsilon)$ goes to $-\infty$  Is this enough?

Comment: @luka5z yes, from there you see that f is not integrable on the compact set [0,1] $\implies$ f is not locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: so I don't have to employ here simple functions?